# cleanly lining up output

Tags: java, excel, arraylist, text

I have a text file that contains data that was saved using the cvs encryption and I want to open it in java and display it lined up perfectly. I have come to the point of reading it from the text file but now I want it to be split at the commas and now I want to display it all perfectly aligned.

```
 Last, First, car year, car model 
 barry, john, 1956, chevy impala
```

and I want it to display like this:

```
 last      First   car year    car model 
 barry     john    1956       chevy impala
```

and I am just using the scanner class to get the data from the text file.

Answer (score 1):

Determine the max lengths of the column values (including column headers), then create a format String and use that format string to build the aligned rows:

```
// some easy magic first
String[][] values = getCsvValues(file);
int[] maxLengths = determineMaxLengths(values);

// create formatstring, something like "%10s %5s %10s %n"
StringBuilder formatBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (int maxLength:maxLengths)
  formatBuilder.append("%").append(maxLength).append("s ");
formatBuilder.append("%n");   // newline

// output
for (String[] row:values)
  System.out.printf(formatBuilder.toString, row);
```

Comment: but the program can accept any input so a set condition is not likely the way to go.

Comment: what do you see as the "set condition" above?

Comment: I don't know how big the csv data set is. so getCsvValues(file) wouldn't work.

Comment: @chuck - why not? You'll have to read the file anyway. Otherwise you need to know the maximum column sizes to do a proper alignment. Aligning without knowing actual column widths is quite impossible.

Comment: now I found out the maximum column number but not the row number

Answer (score 0):

depending on how certain you need to be that it all lines up, you might have to go through and find the longest string for each column, but I would use tabs: `"\t"`. Two or three between columns usually works for me, for simple debugging that's what I use.

If you're really serious about it being right all the way down, try looking at [Formatter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)s and [printf](http://file:///C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_25/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29).

Comment: how would I implement the printf because on the coding side all I have is system.out.printf(arraylist.get(i));

Comment: look at Andreas_D's answer, that's a great way to do it.